# Make a function that looks through an array and returns the animal's object if an animal with that name exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search

I'm a beginner to JS and sadly I've been stuck on this for awhile. I've created an array that holds a bunch of objects of animals that includes the species, names, and noises that they make. I need to write a function with the parameters String which represents the bane of an animal to see if that name exists, and an Array parameter which represents the array of animals. What I have right now (isn't working):

```
function search(array, string){
    if (array.indexOf(string) !== -1){
        return string[animals];
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score -1):

You need to find an object from array of objects on basis of object property. To active that first you need array index then you can apply conditional statement on basis of that index.

```
function search(array, string){
    var index = array.findIndex(x => x.bane === string);
    if (index !== -1){
        return array[index];
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```